# Output of a random generated list has an extra brackets

Tags: string, python-3.x, list, random

Here is my code:

```
     import random    
     def randnum():
        rando = random.sample(range(1000,9999),1)
        strrando = list(str(rando))
        return strrando
```

The purpose is being fulfilled, I am generating a list of 4 randomly generated numbers which are turned to type string. The only problem it generates a list that has a set of brackets as strings in the list itself, so it generates 6 strings instead of the 4. I was wondering if anyone could explain to me why this happens?

Comment: `random.sample` creates a list of numbers, in your case a list with one number. `str()` makes a string out of this list, brackets and all. Do you just want to return one random number with four digits?

Comment: ohhh, i see what you mean, yea I basically want a random 4-digit number generated but then split that number into strings and put in a list.

Comment: Then use [`random.randint(1000,9999)`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/random.html) et voila.